# retrieve the oldest post id

Tags: posts, id

I'm trying to get the ID of the oldest post with the `post_type = job_listing` and `post_status = publish`. I'm using the code below but it does not work. Could anyone please help me

`$oldestID = mysql_query("select id from wp_posts where post_type = 'job_listing' and post_status = 'publish' order by post_date ASC");`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problem in your query (except some poor query writing styles). You did not explain 'does not work'. what you get in return? do you get any errors?

Probably you do not have any `published` `job_listing`!

However, here is how you can improve your given code:

```
$oldest_post_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `id` FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `post_type` = 'job_listing' AND `post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY `post_date` ASC");
```

Please note the `$wpdb->posts` part. this will work safely in any wordpress installations even with custom table prefixes.

you should not use `mysql_query` directly. if you use this query inside a function, you need to include `$wpdb` in your function as below:

```
function myfunc(){
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->show_errors(true);
  $oldest_post_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT `id` FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `post_type` = 'job_listing' AND `post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY `post_date` ASC");
  var_dump($oldest_post_id);
}
```

now, you should get any query error displayed (if any) and `var_dump()` should give you the post ID. otherwise please get back to us what it is returning. when it is working remove **3rd** and **5th** line in the second example.

Comment: Hi HungryCoder, thanks for your detail explanation. I just realized that my code actually worked, i didn't know how to extract the result correctly. For example, `echo $oldest_post_id` gives something like `Resource id #157`. `var_dump($oldest_post_id);` gives something like `object(stdClass)#259 (1) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" }` . What i need is to retrieve the number `17` into a variable. Thanks!

Comment: glad to know that you sorted it out